# How to remove a gunite pool

Tags: pool

How do I remove a 20 X 40 gunite pool safely? I read the other answers and one mentioned being down in the 8 ft end and it could possibly fall in. It popped up out of the ground and I can't afford to pay to have it removed. It's been up for 3 years now. I'm planning on cutting it with a power saw and the proper blade. Starting in the deep end at the top and working my way down carrying up the pieces out of the shallow end. There is rebar and I'm concerned with the saw kicking when it hits that. Has anyone ever tried this? I can't hire this project done. I'm guessing a few hours every night after work and more on weekends to remove it, taking about 3 months to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Rebar doesn't cause kickback with a concrete saw, but it does slow things down. What causes most kickback is binding, which will be somewhat difficult to avoid when cutting horizontally. My shoulders ache just thinking about it.

I'd probably stripe it vertically and cut off the bars at appropriate sizes to minimize horizontal cutting. You'll go though quite a bit of diamond blade, though. Consider renting a small backhoe with a jackhammer attachment.

Comment: I agree with the back hoe, a demo saw is the best way to cut it, I have removed several pools. Renting a gas powered 14" saw will save many hours of work trying to cut through everything the gunite cuts easily but the mesh network of rebar is a real bugger with smaller saws. If you do this in the winter you will probably need a sump pump I know I did even in the summer for the deep end, also you will want to use a good quality respirator some mixes used zonolite with the cement (asbestos laden material) it would be a good idea to have it tested so you can take proper precautions.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I can think of, as I am about to take on the task is a jack hammer. Its the same as breaking up a concrete floor.

Just break the floor first then the walls. You only need to break up a meter from the surface. What I'm going to do with rubble is fill the bottom of the pool and then the top meter or so with top soil

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's speculation that your solution will work.

Comment: I think using a jack hammer is a perfectly good answer, and its what I  would use.

Comment: Yes, but this "answer" isn't based on experience and doesn't include supporting references. It's merely speculation, as JACK said. We're not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for the backhoe idea.  If the gunite is indeed fairly soft then the bucket alone may be able to colaps a side. Then use a bolt cutter, a portable grinder with a cutting wheel and the 14" gas powered saw to deal with the re-bar.  To include and jack-hammer attachment would take the cost to a whole other level. A word of warning: All the tools listed here are not the forgiving kind.  Use an abundance of caution and common sense.  Good Luck. P.